# Possible to delete frames from a video file in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I can open a video and play it with opencv 2 using the `cv2.VideoCapture(myvideo)`. But is there a way to delete a frame within that video using opencv 2? The deletion must happen in-place, that is, the file being played will end up with a shorter time due to deleted frames. Simply zeroing out the matrix wouldn't be sufficient.

For example something like:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(myvideo.flv)

while True:
    img = video.read()

    # Show the image
    cv2.imgshow(img)

    # Then go delete it and proceed to next frame, but is this possible?
    # delete(img)??
```

So the above code would technically contain 0 bytes at the end since it reads then deletes the frame in the video file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV is not the right tool for this job. What you need for this is a media processing framework, like ffmpeg (=libavformat/libavcodec/libswscale) or GStreamer.

Also depending on the encoding scheme used, simply deleting just a single frame may not be possible. Only in a video consisting of just *Intra* frames (I-frames), frame exact editing is possible. If the video is encoding in so called *group of pictures* (GOP) removing a single frame requires to reencode the whole GOP it was part of.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't do it in-place**, but you can use OpenCV's [VideoWriter](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=videocapture#videowriter) to write the frames that you want in a new video file.